# How to create pull request to specific commit

Tags: git-commit, pull-request

I have a forked project with latest commit in master is some C {A->B->C},
and i have another branch say some "dev" with commits ex:A->B->C->X->Y->Z

Now how can i create multiple pull requests(split every commit X,Y,Z as pull request) from my branch.

If is there any possibility , please suggest me...

Answer (score 0):

For each commit:

1. Create branch from master (C in your example);
2. Cherry-pick your commit (X,Y or Z);
3. Create pull-request to master.